# Where should I store non UI data in a react-redux application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

In a React-Redux application I need to store the current url for future reference - After the url has changed, depending on the previous url query I'll take different actions, but this info does't affect the UI directly. The thing is, React state should store only UI related state, as any change will trigger rendering. I guess the same principle should be the case with Redux's state as well? I guess only state properties which will be passed to components via the connected components will trigger rerendering, but still I'm not sure Reudx store is the place to store such info, since this data is watched and that is unnecesary. Can I just store it in a global object I create for this purpose?

Comment: I don't know if redux store is a good place for storing your url (i dont see any reason to avoid it) but you can stop any component from re-rendering by returning false in shouldComponentUpdate() method. so your connected components can only updated when state change is not url related.

Comment: As long as your selectors are extremely specific to the data they are providing the components with and your bottom-level components are the only ones calling these selectors, there should be no unnecessary re-renders. Redux store should be a fine place to put it. I use redux store for routing between screens (as react-router is overkill for my needs) which contains a lot of non-ui meta data and my store survives without any unnecessary re-renders. If you really want to remove it from Redux, consider localStorage or sessionStorage as mentioned in the answers.

Answer (score 2):

It is easy and convenient to store such thing into browser's localStorage (or sessionStorage). Ofc this will persist such data until storage is cleared (or the session ended).

Answer (score 0):

You could put it in the redux state. As long as the corresponding state is not being used by any component a re-render should not be triggered (as the component state is not changing).

Other option as mentioned by someone already is to put it into localStorage.